# Don't Display Entry Date if Same as previous Entry Date in List

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a list of entries containing dates. I would like to only display the date if it is different from the previous entry date.

I am reading in the entries from core data and passing them to the method ckEntryDate for determination of whether to display the date. The method is called from inside a list. If the string returned by ckEntryDate is blank (string.isEmpty) I know that the current entry date is the same as the previous date and I don't need to display the date.

There are no errors occurring, but the current entry date is not being saved via userDefaults. I would appreciate any ideas on how to save the current date or how to check for identical dates.

Thanks

```
struct HistoryView: View {
            @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
            @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
            
    // fetch core data
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CurrTrans.entryDT, ascending: true)]
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { g in
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                ShowTitle(g:g, title: "History")
                ShowHistoryHeader(g: g)
                
                ScrollView (.vertical) {
                    List {
                        
                        ForEach(currTrans, id: \.id) { item in
                            let entryDate = userData.ckEntryDate( item: item)
                            
                            showRow(g:g, item: item, entryDate: entryDate)
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                    }
                    
                }.font(.body)
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is part of the class UserData:  ObservableObject {

```
   // check if history entry date is same as previous date or the first entry
func ckEntryDate( item: CurrTrans) -> (String) {
    
    var outDate: String = ""
    var savedDate: String = ""
    
    //read in savedDate
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "storeDate") != "" {
         savedDate = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "storeDate") ?? ""
    }else {
        savedDate = ""
    }

    // convert Date? to String
    let cdate = item.entryDT ?? Date()
    let currDate = cdate.getFormattedDate()
    
    // check if no previous entries
    if savedDate.isEmpty {
         outDate = currDate
    }
    else {   // savedDate is not blank
        if savedDate == currDate {
             outDate = ""
        }
        else { // date entries different
            outDate = currDate
        }

        savedDate = currDate 
    }

    // save savedDate
    UserDefaults.standard.set(savedDate, forKey: "saveDate")
    return outDate
}
```

}

```
extension Date {
    
    func getFormattedDate() -> String {
        
        // localized date & time formatting
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateStyle = .medium
        dateformat.timeStyle = .none
        return dateformat.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for a way to persist the current entry date for comparison to the next entry date for checking if the dates are the same.

I discovered that I could do this by simply placing a variable at the top of the class that contains the method ckEntryDate.

```
class UserData:  ObservableObject {
    
    var storedDate: String = ""
```

So thanks to all who took the time to consider a possible answers.

```
// check if history entry date is the 1st entry or the same as previous date
    func ckEntryDate( item: CurrTrans) -> (String) {
        var outDate: String = ""
        
        // initialzie the entry date
        let cdate = item.entryDT ?? Date()
        let entryDate = cdate.getFormattedDate()
        
        // if savedDate is blank -> no previous entries
        if storedDate.isEmpty {
             outDate = entryDate
        }
        else {   // savedDate is not blank
            if storedDate == entryDate {
                 outDate = ""
            }
            else { // date entries different
                outDate = entryDate
            }
        }
        storedDate = entryDate
        
        // outDate returns blank or the current date
        return (outDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function `ckEntryDate` works correctly, you could try this approach of filtering the data at the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(currTrans.filter { "" != userData.ckEntryDate(item: $0) }, id: \.id) { item in
    showRow(g:g, item: item, entryDate: userData.ckEntryDate(item: item))
}
```

You can also try this:

```
ForEach(currTrans, id: \.id) { item in
    let entryDate = userData.ckEntryDate(item: item)
    if !entryDate.isEmpty {
        showRow(g:g, item: item, entryDate: entryDate)
    }
}
```